# ADFS Token validation against issuer

Tags: validation, token, adfs, bearer-token

I developed an api which will receives request from a client app (external) and process the request. The client app implemented ADFS (Windows server) token and send this token to api in each and every the request as bearer token. Now in api end, I have to validate the token against the issuer and process the request if token is valid.

Please let me know if any code sample available for this implementation.

Thank you

Selvakumar R

Looking sample code to implement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.